# If I add mods to a server, do the clients have to download them too?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I set up a Forge server, which works just fine.

I know that you need the client to be able to play in it, and I know that my friends needs it too.

But if I add mods to the server, do my friends have to download them as well? If so, where do they put them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my friend and I play minecraft together with different mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152887/can-my-friend-and-i-play-minecraft-together-with-different-mods)

Answer (score 3):

The server and the client have to be in sync, so the answer is **Yes**, your friend has to download the mod(s) as well.

There are many tutorials to find on the internet on how to install mods on a server, like this one:

Your friends should put the mods inside the `%AppData%\.minecraft\mods` folder.

Comment: @codemaster, simply pasting links to a source (in this case, a YouTube video) is frowned upon. It's recommended to actually write (fine; "type") the answer as words.

Comment: That's what I did, I awnserd the question and I added extra info in the form of a YouTube video

Comment: Well, you haven't answered the question fully; I quote: "`and if they do then where do they put them?`" | The video shows the answer; `%AppData%\.minecraft\mods`.

Comment: ahh diden't see that...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mode **ServerSync**.

> This is an open source mod that allows for easy mod management. The client will always be able to connect to your server and you will never again have to send them the new files and tell them to update.

[Here a link to GitHub](https://github.com/superzanti/ServerSync)

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question.