# If I have OptiFine, can I play with someone who doesn't have OptiFine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

If I download OptiFine, can I still play Minecraft with someone who doesn't have OptiFine?

Or will this mess up the game somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my friend and I play minecraft together with different mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152887/can-my-friend-and-i-play-minecraft-together-with-different-mods)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the linked question is only half the truth, and doesn't hold for this case here. Make sure to read the answers below it as well as the comments, both of which explain the concept of "client-side vs server-side".

Answer (score 3):

Optifine is a client-side mod, it only changes how things look for you. Just like a resource pack, the server doesn't need to care about it. So yes, Optifine is fully compatible with Vanilla servers.

Comment: OP should take care which mod version he/she downloads, as some versions of Optifine only work with older Minecraft versions.

Comment: Of course. But it says that pretty clearly on the download page.