# Will Minecraft LAN with friend work if he does not have the same mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

The mods that I don't change the structure of the world or add other significant changes, they just increase my fps. Will LAN work if my friend does not have the same mod installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my friend and I play minecraft together with different mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152887/can-my-friend-and-i-play-minecraft-together-with-different-mods)

Answer (score -2):

No, you must have the same mods folder, with the same versions.

Comment: This is not true. Many mods do not require clients to have matching mods. I run a server with Carpet, NoChatReports, and Lithium and unmodded clients can connect just fine.